# MetaSerialisable object argument after ** must be a mapping, not unicode

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Trying to convert this styler object to xlsx sheet:

```
 avg.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn',low=.09,high=.18,axis=1).to_excel('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
```

[image]

However, I get the error:

```
 TypeError: MetaSerialisable object argument after ** must be a mapping, not unicode
```

and when I try:

```
 avg.style.background_gradient({'cmap':'RdYlGn'},low=.09,high=.18,axis=1).to_excel('test.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')

TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'dict'", u'occurred at index (Gain/Expsr%, 5)')
```

With this one here, there's just no background gradient output:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('usher.xlsx')
df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn').to_excel(writer,engine='openpyxl')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you omit the `to_excel()` part?

Comment: @jmcnamara Nope, the styler object is working fine

Comment: Ok. From the Pandas [Styler](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) docs it looks like `background_gradient` may only be supported in the Html output. And even then the styling that is supported by `to_excel()` is only supported when using `openpyxl` as the Excel engine.

Comment: when I use the openpyxl engine there's still no background gradient output - how would it work with the html output?  .to_html() , but what after that? Thanks John

Comment: Perhaps you could use conditional formatting in Excel via [XlsxWriter and Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-conditional-formatting-to-dataframe-output) instead.

Comment: This works by the way, if you write it in answer i can accept it. Thanks! - xlsx writer is awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pandas Styler is only supported in `to_excel()` when using openpyxl as the Excel engine. Also from the [Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) it looks like background_gradient may only be supported in the Html output.

As an alternative you  use conditional formatting in Excel via [XlsxWriter and Pandas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-conditional-formatting-to-dataframe-output) instead.

```
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format('B2:B8', {'type': '3_color_scale'})

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

[image]